# Discord Bot. Registering slash commands error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I'm trying to make a discord bot for a project and I'm trying to register slash commands but the error:
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[APPLICATION_COMMAND_INVALID_NAME]: Command name is invalid
keeps showing up.

Here's the code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const commands = [
    {
        name: 'Apostole',
        description: 'Informs you of the horrors awaiting on the other side',
    }
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {
      console.log('The Apostole is thinking...');
        
      await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationGuildCommands(
          process.env.CLIENT_ID, 
          process.env.GUILD_ID
          ),
        { body: commands }
      );
      
      console.log('The Apostole has answered.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Unexpected Apostole Intervention.: ${error}`);
    }
})();
```

I am following a tutorial and thus far I have done exactly as it says so I don't understand why this keeps happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use uppercase character inside a command name.

Change this

```js
const commands = [
    {
        name: 'Apostole',
        description: 'Informs you of the horrors awaiting on the other side',
    }
];
```

By:

```js
const commands = [
    {
        name: 'apostole',
        description: 'Informs you of the horrors awaiting on the other side',
    }
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense now that I think about it.